# Sheet binded item doesn't deinitialize SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, automatic-ref-counting, swiftui-sheet

Have the following scenario. Basically I want to use the item binded sheet init and bind it to an optional property which will be set when we want to show the sheet. On the outside it looks perfectly normal but something interesting I am noticing is that the item property isn't getting deinitialized, which leads to a retain cycle, here is a sample:

```swift
class Item: Identifiable {
    var dismiss: () -> Void

    init(dismiss: @escaping () -> Void) {
        self.dismiss = dismiss
        print("init >> item \(Unmanaged.passUnretained(self).toOpaque())")
    }

    deinit {
        print("deinit >> item \(Unmanaged.passUnretained(self).toOpaque())")
    }

    func start() -> some View {
        ViewTwo(dismiss: dismiss)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var item: Item? {
        didSet {
            print(item)
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        Button("Show") {
            item = Item {
                item = nil
            }
        }
        .sheet(item: $item) { item in
            item.start()
        }
    }
}

struct ViewTwo: View {
    var dismiss: () -> Void

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Dismiss") {
                dismiss()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When I run the code it prints "deinit >> item 0x..." to the console so this seems to work as expected at least on iOS 17.4

Comment: Oh, my I was running iOS 17.0 only, yeah works for me on 17.4 as well, damn apple

Comment: Try using structs in Swift